# c# How to merge two data rows & columns into one in datatable by using ItemArray?

Tags: c#, datatable

I would like to produce this output as shown on the image below with ItemArray function, please help :D

Assume im using like dr.ItemArray[0] with index to allocate the row data and merge with respective ItemArray index to get the combined data

[image: Desired Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming dt is your datatable

```
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        row[0] = row[0].ToString() + row[1].ToString();
    }
    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
```

Comment: Thanks man the solution works pretty well as I thought operand + cannot apply to both object